# How can I get the SSRS Report Wizard to allow me to move on?

Tags: reporting-services, wizard

I added a new report to my SSRS project by right-clicking the Reports folder and selecting "Add New Report"

After selecting a sahred data source, the Report Wizard dialog displayed. I clicked through to the query page and added my custom SQL. The next page allowed me to determine where the fields returned from the query would be located in the report.

However, whether I put all of the fields in the "Displayed Fields" box or all but one, putting that one in the "Group" box, I cannot proceed - the "Finish" button is not active.

What must I do to be able to move on and proceed with the wizardification of the report?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce this by attempting to create a matrix report. Matrix reports require at least 1 column,1 row and 1 detail line. Tabular reports don't have this requirement.